# How to use PHP code in inline CSS in HTML

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'd like to use my PHP code in Inline CSS. Let me show the code:

This is my code:

```
<div class="col-auto">
    <div class="h5 mb-0 mr-3 font-weight-bold text-gray-800">%22</div>
</div>
<div class="col">
<div class="progress progress-sm mr-2">
    <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar"
        style="width: <?php $a=22; echo "$a"; ?>%" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0"
        aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

But instead, I get this:

[image]

What can I do to make CSS read `22` from my PHP code? I want to change the `width` by changing the PHP code. By the way I'm using Bootstrap.

Comment: Is that HTML file generated by php?  If you are using that code in a plain HTML file it won't run.

Comment: i just tested your code on a php compiler online, and it works fine!, the file must be a .php file, so is the file a .html of a .php file?

Comment: What is the point of doing `style="width: <?php $a=22; echo "$a"; ?>%"` when its basically the same as `style="width: 22%"` ? You hard coded the 22 so why add the complication of PHP

Comment: Ohhh guys so sorry, it's my bad. I was using .html instead of using .php.  I'm going to change it now. Thanks for noticing me.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm going to get the data from MySQL later. I'm just looking if I can use PHP in CSS now.

Comment: _SMall Point_ You dont need the double quotes `echo $a;` with do and will remove the double quotes in double quotes issue

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks. I deleted double quotes. I'm using `echo $a;` now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

masterguru seems to be right, you're using plain HTML. The code itself is correct, you just need to make sure that the PHP inside the HTML is ran.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3B-CnezwEeo) explains how to serve PHP locally.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I noticed that later.